# UIBezierPath not drawing in drawRect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following code in my UIView drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

   UIBezierPath *trackPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[trackPath addQuadCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(10, 30) controlPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[trackPath stroke];

   }
```

however I am not seeing any path drawn. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you did was create the path. Now try:

```
[aPath stroke];
```

**Update**

In your new and improved question, you need to set the initial point before adding the quad curve:

```
[trackPath moveToPoint:somePoint];
```

Comment: OK, but that wasn't the original question. Next time let's stick to the original question, and move from there instead of changing things in mid-stream. It may be that your control point, being the same as your path's original location (0,0) is causing it to not draw correctly. Also, you might try explicitly setting the stroke color (although it should probably default to black) with `[UIColor someColor] setStroke];`

Comment: The stroke color is set to black

Answer (score 0):

Your code only defines a path. Add:

```
[aPath stroke];
```